# Unclaimed device in lshw

Tags: drivers, hard-disk, hardware, sata

I have added in my computer a PCI Express controler card with 2 USB3 ports and 2 sata3 ports. (http://www.ldlc.be/fiche/PB00121886.html).

The USB ports are working correctly but the HDD plugged in the sata port is not appearing in the devices.

I ran lshw and here the result concerning the pci card:

```
*-pci:1
            description: PCI bridge
            product: PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch
            vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
            physical id: 5
            bus info: pci@0000:05:05.0
            version: ba
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:46 ioport:7000(size=8192) memory:d6100000-d61fffff

    *-ide UNCLAIMED
               description: IDE interface
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: ide msi pm pciexpress cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: ioport:7000(size=8) ioport:7400(size=4) ioport:7800(size=8) ioport:7c00(size=4) ioport:8000(size=16) memory:d6100000-d61001ff`
```

It seems that the Unclaimed IDE is the culprit and that it is unclaimed because the system found no driver for it.
How can I find which driver I would need to make that ide part working?

So far my google search for PEX 8604 return almost nothing concerning a linux driver.

EDIT: additional info

```
# lspci -nn
00:00.0 Memory controller [0580]: nVidia Corporation CK804 Memory Controller [10de:005e] (rev a3)
00:01.0 ISA bridge [0601]: nVidia Corporation CK804 ISA Bridge [10de:0050] (rev f3)
00:01.1 SMBus [0c05]: nVidia Corporation CK804 SMBus [10de:0052] (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation CK804 USB Controller [10de:005a] (rev a2)
00:02.1 USB Controller [0c03]: nVidia Corporation CK804 USB Controller  [10de:005b] (rev a3)
00:04.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: nVidia Corporation CK804 AC'97 Audio Controller [10de:0059] (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface [0101]: nVidia Corporation CK804 IDE [10de:0053] (rev f2)
00:07.0 IDE interface [0101]: nVidia Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller [10de:0054] (rev f3)
00:08.0 IDE interface [0101]: nVidia Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller [10de:0055] (rev f3)
00:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCI Bridge [10de:005c] (rev f2)
00:0a.0 Bridge [0680]: nVidia Corporation CK804 Ethernet Controller [10de:0057] (rev f3)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge [10de:005d] (rev f3)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge [10de:005d] (rev f3)
00:0d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge [10de:005d] (rev f3)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge [10de:005d] (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration [1022:1100]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map [1022:1101]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller [1022:1102]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control [1022:1103]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] [10de:06e4] (rev a1)
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch [10b5:8604] (rev ba)
05:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch [10b5:8604] (rev ba)
05:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch [10b5:8604] (rev ba)
06:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Device [1b21:1040]
07:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: Device [1b21:0611] (rev 01)
08:06.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
08:0b.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments TSB43AB22/A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [104c:8023]
08:0c.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8001 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4320] (rev 13)


# lspci -v -s 5:5
05:05.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00008fff
    Memory behind bridge: d6100000-d61fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a4] Subsystem: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8604 4-lane, 4-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number [EDITED]
    Capabilities: [fb4] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [520] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [950] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=0 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

# lspci -v -s 7:0
07:00.0 IDE interface: Device 1b21:0611 (rev 01) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Device 1b21:1060
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 7000 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 7400 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 7800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 7c00 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 8000 [size=16]
    Memory at d6100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

Comment: What are the device vendor/product id's? Use `lspci -nn`.

Comment: I think PEX 8604 is just the PCIe bridge. It doesn't really do anything but taking care of interconnections. `lspci -v -s 5:5` should show a lot more information.

Comment: For lspci, `07:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: Device [1b21:0611] (rev 01)` is the device. And in lshw, it does show `capabilities: ide msi pm pciexpress cap_list`. Is the drive plug in to that interface working? spinning? Has power?

Comment: The disk was properly plugged. I solved my problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution. The device was unclaimed because it was not known correctly by the kernel.

Using a kernel 3.5, the device was listed as below:

```
*-ide UNCLAIMED
               description: IDE interface
               product: ASM1061 SATA IDE Controller
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: ide msi pm pciexpress cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: ioport:7000(size=8) ioport:7400(size=4) ioport:7800(size=8) ioport:7c00(size=4) ioport:8000(size=16) memory:d6100000-d6100
```

but it was still unclaimed.

When searching for the device [1b21:0611] I found a [post](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1206.0/00986.html) in the kernel mailing list talking about it. It tells that the kernel does not identify the device correctly as an ahci device and propose a patch to the kernel.

```
--- a/drivers/ata/ahci.c    2012-05-20 23:56:54.000000000 +0200
+++ b/drivers/ata/ahci.c    2012-05-31 14:51:01.577045033 +0200
@@ -391,6 +391,9 @@
{ PCI_VDEVICE(PROMISE, 0x3f20), board_ahci },   /* PDC42819 */

/* Asmedia */
+ { PCI_VDEVICE(ASMEDIA, 0x0601), board_ahci }, /* ASM106x */
+ { PCI_VDEVICE(ASMEDIA, 0x0602), board_ahci }, /* ASM106x */
+ { PCI_VDEVICE(ASMEDIA, 0x0611), board_ahci }, /* ASM1061 */
{ PCI_VDEVICE(ASMEDIA, 0x0612), board_ahci },   /* ASM1061 */

/* Generic, PCI class code for AHCI */
```

I applied the patch to the source of kernel 3.5 and recompiled and it is now working. For information, the patch is included in the kernel in the release 3.6 and above.

Comment: If anyone comes to this years later, if you compile Linux from source, make sure to include the usb kernel modules as well.